# How to bring back offline database in SQL Server 2008

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, offline

I wanted to restore a database, so I tried to take current database offline, but it was taking too long to get offline, hence I stopped the process. But now when I try to access the database, it says database inaccessible.

Does that means it's lost forever now? I even tried to kill active connection, it shows command successful however I'm still not able to restore database.

Can anyone help with getting it back?

Comment: what does errorlog say?

Comment: can you connect in single user mode? http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/01/09/sql-server-sqlcmd-using-a-dedicated-administrator-connection-to-kill-currently-running-query/

Answer (score 3):

Database is made offline to move its physical files. There can be many ways to make a database offline. But there are three main methods which are used frequently to make the database offline. These methods are given below:-

**1) With the help of Alter database Command**

We can make the database offline or online with the help of the Alter database command. The Alter Database command to make the database offline is:

```
ALTER DATABASE database name SET Offline
```

If we want to make the database online we can use the following Alter Database command:

```
ALTER DATABASE database name SET Online
```

**2) With the help of the Db_options**

We can also use the db_options command to make a database offline or online.To make a database offline we can use the following command:

```
sp_dboption databasename ,'offline',true
```

To make the database online we can use the following command:

```
sp_dboption databasename ,'offline',false
```

**3) With the help of Sql server management studio**

We can also use the Sql server management studio to make a database offline / online.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the suspect mode.
Check the error log once and move forward based on that.

You try with following commands

```
Alter database [Name of DB] set offline with rollback immediate.
```

After using this above commons if u want to come to online again follow the below commond

```
Alter database  [Name of DB] set online
```